# What do we call this quantifier ("binder")?

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science, foundations, formal-languages, type-theory

There's a quantifier ("binder", whatever), call it $\alpha$, defined as follows:  $\alpha x.\tau$ is the (usually infinite) expression obtained by applying the substitution $\{x \mapsto \tau\}$ to the expression $x$ an infinite number of times. Its probably a bit unclear what I mean here, so let me give some intuition and a couple of examples.

The idea is to read $\alpha x.(x+1)$ as denoting an infinite syntactic expression corresponding to the equation $x=x+1$. In particular, suppose $x=x+1$. Then we can write: $$x = x+1 = (x+1)+1 = ((x+1)+1)+1) = \cdots$$

We think of $\alpha x.(x+1)$ as the 'limit' of this process. So: $$\alpha x.(x+1) = ((...)+1)+1.$$

Notice there's no $x$ in the 'expression' $((...)+1)+1$; once we've passed to infinity, all our variables disappear. So $x$ is 'bound' in the expression $\alpha x.(x+1).$ Its not free. In some sense, we might say: there's no $x$ in $\alpha x.(x+1).$

More generally, we're meant to think of $\alpha x.\tau$ as the infinite expression corresponding to the assumption $x=\tau$. For instance:

$$\alpha x.(x+x) = ((...)+(...))+((...)+(...))$$

etc.

> **Question.** What do we call this 'quantifier' and where can I learn more about it?

I'm also interested in variants and generalizations, so don't be hesitant to post an answer even if it doesn't *quite* answer the question.

Comment: Do you need to use a hole punch before using a binder?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you'd want to give it a name.  Why not use standard $\lim$ notation? *Discrete dynamical system* is another standard name for the kind of thing you're doing.

Comment: @RyanBudney, well, I suspect it has a name. And I like knowing the names of things that I'm interested in when they have names. Further to that, I'd like to use it in a foundational context in which topology/order theory 'isn't yet available'. That being said, I'd be interested to know whether this can indeed be interpreted as a limit in an appropriately chosen topological space.

Comment: @RyanBudney, regarding the comment about discrete dynamical systems - I don't know anything about that field, but I suspect that $\alpha$ is somehow the dual of all that. For example $\alpha x.(x+1)$ isn't $$((x+1)+1)+ \cdots,$$ its $$((...)+1)+1.$$ The expression *ends*, and the $x$ vanishes.

Comment: This seems to be an iterator rather than a quantifier. Anyway, while it is fairly unclear to me what want to do with the thing, you probably want to look at [corecursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, no the hole punch is optional. For example, the universal hole punch, which 'pierces' the universe, needn't be used before the teaching of the universal quantifier to 1st year university students. But feel free to use it, of course, if wormholes are your thing :)

Comment: I don't really see the difference.  Some people express functions with an explicit variable, like $f(x) = \sin(x)$.  Others find the variable redundant, $f = \sin$.  You can do it any way you like.

Comment: You might be thinking of the idea of a fixed-point combinator from computer science.

Comment: Is this related to your research?

Comment: Perhaps 'infinitary lambda calculus' might be a good thing to google to look for answers and related things.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf, kind of. I'm not yet far enough into my career to be doing formal research per se, but there's stuff I'm toying with privately that relates to $\alpha$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are describing the [regular tree grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_tree_grammar). Here is the basic idea.

It is useful to think of syntactic expressions as [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). In our case we are looking for a tree $\alpha$ which satisfies the equation
$$\alpha = \alpha + 1$$
The tree is infinite, but it is also regular (both intuitively and in a precise formal sense):

[image]

In general you might want to solve a *system* of such equations, for instance
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma \\
\beta &= 1 + \beta \\
\gamma &= (\gamma + \beta)
\end{align*}
gives the infinite epression $\alpha$ indicated by
$$
(1 + (1 + (1 + \cdots))) + ((\cdots + (1 + (1 + (1 + \cdots)))) + (1 + (1 + (1 + \cdots)))).
$$

Regarding the question "What is this binder called?" the answer is **a (least) fixed-point operator**. It is usually written as $\mu$ or $\mathsf{fix}$ and its defining equation is, unsurprisingly,
$$\mu x \,.\, \phi(x) = \phi(\mu x \,.\, \phi(x).$$
Your fixed-point operator works at the level of syntax as it is building an infinite syntactic tree. There are other fixed point operators. For instance, given a monotone map $f : L \to L$ on a complete lattice, $\mu f$ would be the least fixed point of $f$. Such operators are the basis of recursive and inductive definitions in programming languages, and have many other uses as well.

Comment: A small addendum: these structures have very close connections with the Anti-Foundation Axiom (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom) which essentially posits that _any_ such system has a solution.

Comment: Right, I think the Wikipedia page I linked to mentions these things.

Comment: Do you know if this have anything to do with [domain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory)?

Comment: Well, not really, unless you have something particular in mind.

Comment: Just that we should be able to define $\mu x.(x+1)$ as the join of a chain of expression in an appropriate poset; I thought maybe domain theory was kind of about this. (I don't have a CS background, as you can probably tell.)

Comment: Yeah, you can do it in domain theory but these fixed-point equations are quite simple (they are covariant) and can be solved in ordinary set theory.